# Finding max element in a list in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list which is defined as

```
L=[45,56,98,75,90,12,64]
```

I have another list is as follows

```
M=[True,True,False,True,False,True,True]
```

Now I want to find the max element from the list L whose corresponding entry in list M is True. In other words, I want to get the max value from L as 75 since 98 and 90 are marked as False in list M.

How can I code this in Python using lambda expressions?

Answer (score 1):

May be the easiest way to do this is
`max([L[i] for i in range(0, len(L)) if M[i]])`

And you can define a lambda expression as,

`g = lambda L,M: max([L[i] for i in range(0, len(L)) if M[i]]);`

Then

`print(g(L,M))` will give you 75.